# Performance of Java enums

Tags: java, internationalization, enums

I was thinking about using `enum` type to manage i18n in a Java game I'm developing but I was curious about performance issues that can occur when working with enums that have lots of elements (thousands I think).

Actually I'm trying something like:

```
public enum Text {
  STRING1,
  STRING2,
  STRING3;

  public String text() {
    return text;
  }

  public String setText() {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

Then to load them I can just fill the fields:

```
static
{
  Text.STRING1.setText("My localized string1"); 
  Text.STRING2.setText("My localized string2"); 
  Text.STRING3.setText("My localized string3"); 
}
```

Of course when I'll have to manage many languages I'll load them from a file.

What I'm asking is

- is an obect allocated (in addition to the string) for every element? (I guess yes, since enums are implemented with objects)
- how is the right element retrieved from the enum? is it static at compile time? (I mean when somewhere I use `Text.STRING1.text()`). So it should be constant complexity or maybe they are just replaced during the compiling phase..
- in general, is it a good approach or should I look forward something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found and adapted a nice mix of enums and ResourceBundle:

```
public enum Text {
  YELL, SWEAR, BEG, GREET /* and more */ ;

  /** Resources for the default locale */
  private static final ResourceBundle res =
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.Messages");

  /** @return the locale-dependent message */
  public String toString() {
    return res.getString(name() + ".string");
  }
}
```

---

```
# File com/example/Messages.properties
# default language (english) resources
YELL.string=HEY!
SWEAR.string=§$%&
BEG.string=Pleeeeeease!
GREET.string=Hello player!
```

---

```
# File com/example/Messages_de.properties
# german language resources
YELL.string=HEY!
SWEAR.string=%&$§
BEG.string=Biiiiiitte!
GREET.string=Hallo Spieler!
```

Comment: Since you're still around, what's your current take on this approach, 4.5 years later? :)

Answer (score 11):

You're probably better off using the `java.util.ResourceBundle` class. It is designed to solve exactly this problem.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, there is exactly one instance of each enum value.
2. Yes, constant complexity for looking up an Enum value.
3. Not really. Changing the content/behaviour of the enum kinda defeats the purpose of having enums in the first place. They're supposed to represent fixed-range constants with type safety. You *can* do this kind of thing but that's not what they were designed for.

Comment: Yes, but, OTH, enums haven't been designed to replace the Singleton pattern too - but they did ;-) I agree on (1) and (2) but would need stronger arguments for (3)

Comment: @Andreas: They've replaced Singleton? Not in my code! A stronger argument for 3? Sure! Just use a ResourceBundle. Problem solved, much easier.

Comment: @Cameron - wow - don't tell the SO Java gurus that you still use the old Java Singleton pattern ;-)

Comment: @Andreas: I guess it does get you a lot for free. Feels hacky, but on reflection I suppose it does make a lot of sense. Maybe I'll become a guru yet :)

Comment: I know about `ResourceBundle` but I didn't like to have a `String` as  the key to the localized text. I rather prefer having a symbol (like enum's ones) so that's why I was trying to solve it with enums. Also for IDE autocompletion during development :)

Comment: You can have a big pile of static final Strings somewhere. So the Text class can have `public final static String STRING1 = "STRING1"` and you look up the resource bundle with `getString(Text.STRING1)`. Your code now looks exactly like you're using an Enum and the IDE should recognise the constants. You can even use static imports if you want.

Answer (score 7):

I hate to hijack to topic, but relying on enums for i18n is going to eventually paint you into a corner.  Java has proper i18n support, even going so far as to have a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html) for it.

Answer (score 2):

although java has i18n support using ResourceBundle I do not think that idea to use enum for this purpose is so bad. I believe that these 2 approaches can be merged. You can create `enum Texts` that contains all your text identifiers. You can create resource bundles for each supported language and use the same identifiers in this bundle.

Then implement `getText()` method in the enum as following:

```
return ResourceBundle.getBundle("texts").getString(name());
```

So, you do not have to care about the initialization of texts for each language. The standard mechanism cares about this.

Now you use in code the enums and enjoy all features of bundles. You can also create unit test that verifies that all enum members have appropriate lines in bundle and vice versa to avoid garbage in your bundles.

I will probably use this approach in my next project. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: you're welcome :) I'll take a look to your solution, it seems quite complete and simple at the same time (while keeping the fact that I can reference string with symbols instead that strings, that was my main purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for showing me a compiler error I have never seen before. When compiling the source file generated by:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("C:\\test.java");
    w.println("enum Test {");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        w.println("c" + i + ",");
    }
    w.println("}");
    w.close();
}
```

eclipse says

> The code for the static initializer is
>   exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Same test with a mere 2000 constants compiles flawlessly.

Of course, if you have that many constants, it would be a good idea to organize them into more than one source file.

Yes, one (and only one) object is allocated for every enum constant. With 2000 constants, that's a whopping 16KB memory :-)  (on Sun's 32-bit VM, other VMs might differ a little)

Each enum constant is an object, and each of them has a field `text`. The field is not final, and hence not subject to inlining. Yes, field access is constant-time.

However, in general it's wierd having mutable state in an enum. It's possible, though.

Good approaches include:

Delegate to a ResourceBundle as AlexR shows. Disadvantage: You have to manually manage the resource files. If you do that, I recommend a UnitTest to detect mistyped/missing/superfluous resource keys, or even a command line utility to append the missing keys to the resource file so you don't have to (mis-)type them.

If you only support a few languages, you can alternatively store all languages in the enum:

```
enum Message {
    Hello("Hello", "Hallo", "Salut");

    String en;
    String de;
    String fr;

    Message(String en, String de, String fr) {
        this.en = en;
        this.fr = fr;
        this.it = it;
    }
```

Disadvantages: No editing by laymen (needs a compiler), and the source file encoding had better support all special characters in the target language (unicode escapes are awkward ...). Also, the source file gets cluttered if you have more than 3 or 4 languages.

Advantages: Adding/Deleting texts is a snap, and the compiler catches all typos in the name of the text, and the "resource file" is always consistent.

Either way, you should use `MessageFormat` as the tutorial R.Bemrose links to in his answer explains.

And finally, when working with Enums you might find the values() method handy:

```
for (Text t : Text.values()) {

}
```

Comment: You can make the `text` field final, however, initializing it from a resource file chosen by language includes some black magic (and isn't something I'd recommend).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that an enum is best for the keys of I18n rather than the strings they translate to.
However to your specific problem, you should a constructor rather than a setter.  IMHO, In fact you should use a constructor in 90%+ of cases where a value is set on construction and not changed rather than using a setter.

```
public enum Text {
  STRING1("String one"),
  STRING2("String two"),
  STRING3("String two");

  private final String text;
  private Text(String text) { this.text = text; }
}
```

In terms of performance of creating enums, you shouldn't worry about it for a game, clarify and flexibility should be considered first.  A 1000 enums might add 1 ms to the startup time of your app. c.f. Loading the text from a file is likely to add 10 ms.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using a constructor + a `final` field but this wouldn't allow me to change the language at runtime.

Comment: The `constructor` solution has one disadvantage: You'll have to compile one `Text.java` file per language and if you forget one enum in single file, the running JVM might throw nasty errors at the poor player. One common enum file and one setup class per language is less risky. (`text` should be initialized with an empty string or the message from the original language)

Comment: Like I said, I would use the enum for the key alone.  The keys would be the same for all lanugages, only the translations would change.  So you would have a Map<Text, String> which you load for a properties file.